WANem Emulator and two VM hosts configuration
enter image description here
The below are the configurations I made ,
`
WANEM IP - 192.168.1.111
255.255.255.0
Client
Windows IP - 192.168.1.10
255.255.255.0
Default gateway - 192.168.1.111
It is a Windows 10 VM
Server
Linux IP - 192.168.1.50
255.255.255.0
Default gateway -192.168.1.111
It is Ubuntu 24.04 Version latest image
Ping from client ip to server ip and vice versa works
I added the below routes,
Windows,
route add 192.168.1.50 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.111
Linux,
route add -host 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.111
Change of routing table is not working/ showing correct outputs.
From client if I run the command “tracert 192.168.1.50” -  IP address of server. In the output I am not
be able to see the route passing thru “wanemip”, the IP address of the WANem.
From server if I run the command “tracert 192.168.1.10 - IP address of client. In the output I am not
be able to see the route passing thru “wanemip”, the IP address of the WANem.
The attached image is the output of the windows route print:
Are the configurations correct? can anyone look into this and let me know where I am going wrong.enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What is WANem ? A virtual machine ? The bare metal host ? A router ? Why would you define routes in the client and server ? They are in the same subnet so you have no need for routing. The persistent routes to .10 over .111 you made why ? The persistent route to .40 is another mistery, along with 111.0 over 116.129. You need to pick up a book on networking, this is a giant mess. Thirdly, since they are VMs and you havent shared any information on how hosts or guests networking is handled.
